# Problema ao fazer migração com Python e Django: no such column: forum_thread.slug

Tags: python, django, migrations

Estou com esse problema no meu codigo:

`OperationalError at /admin/forum/thread/
no such column: forum_thread.slug`

Já tentei fazer um milhão de mudanças e não consegui. Quando rodo o comando  `python manage.py makemigrations` retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'slug' to thread without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
>   Please select a fix:
>    1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
>    2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
>   Select an option:

Abaixo o meu models.py:

https://github.com/MarcusWiilo/Django-Aplications/blob/master/pro_final/pro_final/forum/models.py

O arquivo completo se encontra aqui:

https://github.com/MarcusWiilo/Django-Aplications/tree/master/pro_final

Agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem diz que vc esta adicionando um campo "non-nullable", em um banco de dados que ja tem registros, mas vc não definiu um valor default para esse campo. A mensagem te oferece 2 opcões: 1) informar um valor default para esse campo ou "abortar" a operação e corrigir o problema no model.
Voce deve fazer uma das duas, informar um valor default ou ir no seu model e adicionar no campo:

```
slug = models.SlugField(...., null=True, blank=True)
```

Com isso voce pode criar o campo, ai fazer as alteracoes necessarias, e depois tornar false esses dois parametros, se for necessario.

Ou vc poderia ter informado um valor default para o campo, assim:

```
slug = models.SlugField(...., default='Valor default blah blah')
```

Se o banco for de testes, talvez seja mais conveniente excluir o banco, as migraçoes e reconstrui-lo.